# Retriving values from generated text box using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have generated one text box and file upload button using jquery as below

```
$(this).before("<div class='col-lg-12'><div class='row'><div class='col-lg-4'><input name='refusal_str[]' type='text'  placeholder='Enter File description'></div><div class='col-lg-4'><input name='refusal[]' type='file'></div></div></div>");
```

I am using foreach to retrieve values of multipe files upload from respective upload button. Now i want to retrieve values from text box and both text box value along with path of the file need to be inserted into table.

```
foreach($_FILES['refusal']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $_FILES['refusal']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['refusal']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['refusal']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['refusal']['type'][$key];    

        // retrieving text box value
        $testi_text=$_REQUEST["testi_text"][$key];
```

when i do this, i am getting the below error:

```
Uninitialized string offset: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access the `testi_text` entry with PHP, but your HTML says it's called `refusal_str[]`, so you need to access that instead:

```
// retrieving the text box value
$testi_text = $_REQUEST['refusal_str'][$key];
```

P.S. A `var_dump($_REQUEST);` should show you what values you've received from your form.